# Move to another view controller when the pin map tapped in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have multi pin on my map (for restaurants), I would like to be directed on a view controller which would present the details of the restaurant tapped (every restaurant has an id).

Objective: When I click on the a restaurant pin I want to go to that detail ViewController (that loads with the id of that restaurant)

This is my code

```
-(void)addAnnotationAtLat: (float)lat long:(float)longi titreEvent:(NSString *)titre sousTitreEvent:(NSString *)sousTitre
{
MKCoordinateRegion Bridge = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} }; 
Bridge.center.latitude = lat;
Bridge.center.longitude = longi;
Bridge.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
Bridge.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;

MKPointAnnotation *ann = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
ann.title = titre;
ann.subtitle = sousTitre;
ann.coordinate = Bridge.center;
[_mapResto addAnnotation:ann];
}


-(void)placeRestaurantSurLaCarte: (NSTimer *)timer{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Restaurant"];
self.restauArray = [[query whereKey:@"adresse" nearGeoPoint:self.point withinKilometers:100] findObjects];
for (PFObject *restau in self.restauArray) {
NSArray *boxes = restau[@"boxes"];
PFGeoPoint *coordinate = restau[@"adresse"];
[self addAnnotationAtLat:coordinate.latitude long:coordinate.longitude titreEvent:restau[@"nom"] sousTitreEvent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Nombre de boxe disponible :%lu",(unsigned long)boxes.count]];
}
```

Could you please give me any help ?

Comment: Welcome! Did you take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: And the map view delegate methods?

Comment: Yes now i can go to the detail view controller but i can't get the id of the restaurant tapped

Comment: See comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241416/get-details-for-selected-annotation.

Comment: Thank you I will see that :)

Answer (score 0):

implement the following delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    // get the annotation object
    id annotation = view.annotation; // replace id with with your annotation class
    // get the id
    NSInteger whateverID = annotation.whateverID;
    // create the detailviewcontroller
    UIViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"STORYBOARDIDENTIFIER"];
    detailViewController.whateverID = whateverID;
    // push the detailviewcontroller
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thank you, but using this method i get the id of the annotation view not the id of the restaurant

Comment: Show me how you add your annotations to the mapview please!

Comment: -(void)addAnnotationAtLat: (float)lat long:(float)longi titreEvent:(NSString *)titre sousTitreEvent:(NSString *)sousTitre
{
    MKCoordinateRegion Bridge = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
    Bridge.center.latitude = lat;
    Bridge.center.longitude = longi;
    Bridge.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    Bridge.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    
    MKPointAnnotation *ann = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    ann.title = titre;
    ann.subtitle = sousTitre;
    ann.coordinate = Bridge.center;
    [_mapResto addAnnotation:ann];
}

Comment: ok. in that case there is no connection between a restaurant and the annotations. you have to rethink about that and create your own class conforming to the mkannotation protocol!

Comment: -(void)placeRestaurantSurLaCarte: (NSTimer *)timer{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Restaurant"];
self.restauArray = [[query whereKey:@"adresse" nearGeoPoint:self.point withinKilometers:100] findObjects];
for (PFObject *restau in self.restauArray) {
    NSArray *boxes = restau[@"boxes"];
    PFGeoPoint *coordinate = restau[@"adresse"];
    [self addAnnotationAtLat:coordinate.latitude long:coordinate.longitude titreEvent:restau[@"nom"] sousTitreEvent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Nombre de boxe disponible :%lu",(unsigned long)boxes.count]];
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `GMSMapViewDelegate`, specifically this method

`mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool`

And when you are creating pins, give them some info that you can use in the `pin.userData` property.

After that in the method you just implemented you call `performSegueWithIdenfier` and pass the value to the detail view controller in

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```